# Angular.js: ng-disabled based on sub-string in object array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, input

In my project, I have some todos. The input should be disabled if a user enter a todo item with the substring `clean`, so inputs of cleaning, clean, cleaner, etc. should disable the input.

In my angular controller, I wrote this method to disable the input based on the substring.

```
$scope.disableInput = function (todos) {
    todos.forEach(function (item) {

        if (item.toLowerCase().indexOf('clean') > -1) {

            return true;
        } else {

            return false;
        }
    });
};
```

In my html file, I have added the `ng-disabled` to the input.

```
    <form ng-submit="addTodo();">
        <input type="text" ng-model="todoText" ng-disabled="disableInput(todos)">
        <input type="submit" value="add">
    </form>
```

It works if I set it to true manually, but it doesn't respond to the return value of the `disableInput` method. I wanted to check the `todos` object every time when a new item is submitted and disable based on the substring.

**How can I return the `true` value from the `disableInput` method back to the template so that the input becomes disabled?**

[JSFiddle version](http://jsfiddle.net/mtbtj9g0/)

The full example was adopted from [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dakra/U3pVM/) and the disable functionality added.

Answer (score 0):

In your function (below) you're iterating over a collection and returning a bool on the first object, that should ring some bells.

```
$scope.disableInput = function (todos) {
todos.forEach(function (item) {

    if (item.toLowerCase().indexOf('clean') > -1) {

        return true;
    } else {

        return false;
    }
});
```

};

'I wanted to check the todos object every time when a new item is submitted'

Sounds like a sensible place to add that check is in the function executed when you add a todo.

Now you don't have to iterate over your todos.

```
var disableInput = function (input) {
    if(input.toLowerCase().indexOf('clean') > -1){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
};
```

So you'll want to add a variable to the scope to keep track of whether the input is disabled.

```
$scope.disabled;
```

Now in your addTodo function (grabbed from your fiddle) you should add the check for the 'clean' string on what's just been input.

```
 $scope.addTodo = function() {
    $scope.todos.push({
       text:$scope.todoText,
       done:false
     });

     //Set the scope variable you just made to the result of the above function
     $scope.disabled = disableInput($scope.todoText);

     $scope.todoText = '';
  };
```

So finally in your mark-up; assign the disabled variable to ng-disabled.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="todoText"  size="30"
 placeholder="add new todo here" ng-disabled="disabled">
```

Here's your modified fiddle I used to play around with.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mtbtj9g0/26/)

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Is there a way to avoid the $scope variable `disable`? I am asking because in the full project, I am displaying multiple users on the same page with one input for every user and only the one field for the particular user should be disabled. When `$scope.disable` all get disabled. Sorry, I didn't mention that to avoid complexity.